# Laravel - how to make a review by buyer for the product?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to ask Bro, how to make a product review by the user who has bought the goods, I've tried to make, but not successful, the result is like this:

first, if the user (buyer) buy the goods and do the review is successful, but the form for the review is still there ... how do I remove the form for the user (buyer) who has done a review for the goods?

[can do a review, when the product has not been reviewed #View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8t5B.png)

[the form still exists despite having reviewed the goods #View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlmfA.png)

secondly, it is already purchased and reviewed by other users, the user (buyer with different account) make a purchase and succeed, but if make a review of the same item, can not the form does not appear, but already made a purchase ..

[there is no form for the user, even after making a purchase #View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imkGC.png)

**essentially like this**
if the goods have not been reviewed, can do the review and the form is still there even though it has done a review.
but if you already have a review, other users (buyers) can not review the item (the form does not appear).
well that's the problem where is Bro ?, in conditioning _ (if) _? or anything else?

**viewproduct.blade.php**

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
<h2>Reviews</h2>
@foreach($reviews as $data)
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <h4>{{ $data->user['name'] }}</h4>
        <p>{{ $data->ulasan }}</p>
        <h3>{{ $data->rating }}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
@if(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->id == $show->order['user_id'])
@if($errors->any())
<div class="alert alert-warning">
<ul>
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
<li>{{ $error }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
</div>
@endif
//form for review (I cut the code)
@endif
</div>
```

**StoreController.php**

```
public function ViewProduct($id)
{
    $show = Products::findOrFail($id);
    $related = Products::where('kategori_id', $show->kategori_id)
    ->orderByRaw('RAND()')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
    $reviews = Reviews::where('product_id', $show->id)->get();
    return view('shop.viewproduct', compact('show','related','order','reviews'));
}

public function StoreReviewProduct(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'rating' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required|min:10',
    ]);
    $addreview = new Reviews([
        'product_id' => $request['product_id'],
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'rating' => $request['rating'],
        'description' => $request['description']
    ]);
    $addreview->save();
    Session::flash('success','thanks for adding review!');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Products(Model).php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['kategori_id','nama_product','deskripsi','harga','pict','stok','review','id_kios'];

    public function kios()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Kios::class,'id_kios');
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Orders::class,'id','product_id');
    }
}
```

thanks a lot for the answer :)

Comment: Does the user logged in when buy something? Buying a product disables the option of other users to review?

Comment: Whatever happens with your data after first review is made is the problem. But I'm pretty sure you don't show us the code which is actually at fault here.

Comment: @jeugen the user has logged in when buying something, the problem after the user bought the goods, and review the goods, other users can not do a review for the same item

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Well, the problem now is where, please help me find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are already set up with your Reviews model.

In your Products model, you could consider creating a function that returns a boolean for whether or not a review has been submitted by the current user. This will allow you to set an @if condition in your blade file.

#### Products.php

```
public function reviews(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Reviews::class);
}

public function currentUserHasSubmittedReview(){
    $countOfReviews = $this->reviews()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('product_id', $this->id)
        ->get();

    return ($countOfReviews > 1 ? true : false); 
}
```

Then in your blade:

#### viewproduct.blade.php

```
@if($product->currentUserHasSubmittedReview() == false)

 <!-- REVIEW CODE -->

@endif
```

Please let me know if there are questions about how this would work.

Answer (score 0):

You should make another field *(boolean)* `is_buyed` on `'product'` table.
When someone (usually first user) buy the product -> `'is_buyed'` field should be updated to true.
After this you can check `Auth::user() && Auth::user()->id == $show->order['user_id'] && !$product->is_buyed`

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I follow the above way has not been resolved yet

Comment: @TofaMaulanaIrvan you should index product somehow to tell this product has a review ...

Comment: @TofaMaulanaIrvan is right. You should index the purchase or a product by a customer. You should NOT add a is_bought column to your main products table as this will not allow for multiple reviews. I will take more time and provide an answer below.

Comment: @MattMcAlister this was a comment from Tofa Maulana Irvan: "the user has logged in when buying something, the problem after the user bought the goods, and review the goods, other users can not do a review for the same item" ... so other users can not review bought and reviewed product - only the buyer, so I think product should be tagged somehow.