# Collection could not be converted to int Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I  want a user to review(rate) a product only once, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474835/laravel-how-to-make-a-review-by-buyer-for-the-product) and tried but I'm getting an error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to int` how can I fix this so that a user will be able to review a product once.

Product.php

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductReview::class);
}

 public function currentUserHasSubmittedReview(){
    $countOfReviews = $this->reviews()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('product_id', $this->id)
        ->get();

    return ($countOfReviews > 1 ? true : false);  //Error comes from this line
}
```

ProductReview.php

```
 public function product()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
  }
```

Blade file

```
  @foreach($products as $product)
     @if ($product->currentUserHasSubmittedReview() == false )
     <a " href="#openModal-about">Write review</a>
      @else

      @endif
  @endforeach
```

Comment: change `$countOfReviews > 1` to `$countOfReviews->count()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$countOfReviews` is a `Collection` but you're trying to treat it like an integer by using `> 1`. `> 1` will only return true if there is more than 1 rather than if one exists.

One way to get around this is to use `exists()` instead of `get()` with the query:

```
public function currentUserHasSubmittedReview()
{
    return $this->reviews()
        ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where('product_id', $this->id)
        ->exists();
}
```

The above will be more efficient as well since the database is doing more of the lifting and you're not having to load multiple collection instances just to count them after the fact.

Comment: This removes the error but It doesn't hide the form for the user who has already submitted the review it always return false @Rwd

Comment: @user11710915 Are you wanting it to check if any review exists or more that one review exists?

Comment: I want to check , if the user has already submitted review of that product (then the form should not display) but if not it should display the form. This should apply according to different users @Rwd

Comment: lets say, if user one has already submitted review in product one then the form should not be displayed for user one and if user two has not yet submitted the review then the form should be displayed @Rwd

Comment: @user11710915 I have updated my answer. I'd assumed from your original logic that a user could potentially have more than one review of a product as the logic in your code was saying more than 1 (`> 1`).

Comment: @user11710915 Glad I could help! :)